# Android create dropdownlist without spinner component

Tags: android, spinner

I want to have a dropdownlist like this:

[image]

But i want to pop it up when you click a menu item. So spinner is not a necessary. Is there a standalone dropdownlist, or is it possible i trigger the spinner automatically?

Comment: That is how the spinner use to look, now it just pops up from the spinner itself

Answer (score 2):

You can do this a few ways:

1. Give your item a submenu by putting another `<menu>` element inside the `<item>` tag.
2. Handle the item click yourself and show a [`ListPopupWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html)
3. Create a [`DialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). Override [`onCreateDialog()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onCreateDialog%28android.os.Bundle%29) and use an [`AlertDialog.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) to create the dialog. Call one of the variations of `setSingleChoiceItems()` on the builder to set a list of single choice items to show in the content.

The first method is maybe the easiest since the selection will call back to your `onOptionsItemSelected()` method and you can easily handle it there, but the other options may be of interest to you as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show a dropdown list on an menu item click, you need to use the Spinner object.

Alternatively you can also use the Action bar with drop-down navigation : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown

Comment: The question was specifically on how to not use the Spinner object. You can actually create a Popup manually and then display it with a PopupWindow, which is exactly what Spinner is doing under the hood